# Join operations in SQL

Tags: sql

I should retrieve the IDs and names of ingredients that are not contained by any ice cream and then
sort the output rows in ascending order by ingredient ID. I don't quite understand how JOIN -operation works in this exercise.

I tried e.g. the following but it gives too many rows in the output.

```
SELECT ingredient.ingredient_id, ingredient.ingredient_name
FROM ingredient
LEFT JOIN contains ON ingredient.ingredient_id != contains.ingredient_id
LEFT JOIN ice_cream ON ice_cream.ice_cream_id != contains.ice_cream_id
ORDER BY ingredient.ingredient_id;
```

**Output columns should be as follows:**

```
ingredient_id  ingredient_name

----------------------------

6              Dark chocolate
```

**and here are the tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
    manufacturer_id INT,
    manufacturer_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_id),
    UNIQUE (manufacturer_name)
);

-- jäätelöitä
-- ice creams

CREATE TABLE ice_cream (
    ice_cream_id INT,
    ice_cream_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    manufacturer_id INT NOT NULL,
    manufacturing_cost NUMERIC(4,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ice_cream_id),
    UNIQUE (ice_cream_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES manufacturer
);

-- aineksia
-- ingredients
-- plant_based arvo 0 merkitse ei ja arvo 1 merkitsee kyllä
-- plant_based value 0 means no and value 1 means yes 

CREATE TABLE ingredient (
    ingredient_id INT,
    ingredient_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    kcal INT,
    protein NUMERIC(3,1),
    plant_based INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id),
    UNIQUE (ingredient_name)
);

-- jäätelöt sisältävät aineksia
-- ice creams contain ingredients

CREATE TABLE contains(
    ice_cream_id INT NOT NULL,
    ingredient_id INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ice_cream_id, ingredient_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ice_cream_id) REFERENCES ice_cream,
    FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient
);




--Ice cream manufacturers
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES (
    1, 'Jen & Berry', 'Canada'
);

INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES (
    2, '4 Friends', 'Finland'
);

INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES (
    3, 'Gelatron', 'Italy'
);

--Ice cream

INSERT INTO ice_cream VALUES (
    1, 'Plain Vanilla', 1, 1.00
);

INSERT INTO ice_cream VALUES (
    2, 'Vegan Vanilla', 2, 0.89
);

INSERT INTO ice_cream VALUES (
    3, 'Super Strawberry', 2, 1.44
);

INSERT INTO ice_cream VALUES (
    4, 'Very plain', 2, 1.20
);


--Ingredients
INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    1, 'Cream', 400, 3, 0
);

INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    2, 'Coconut cream', 230, 2.3, 1
);

INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    3, 'Sugar', 387, 0, 1
);

INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    4, 'Vanilla extract', 12, 0, 1
);


INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    5, 'Strawberry', 33, 0.7, 1
);

INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES (
    6, 'Dark chocolate', 535, 8, 1
);


--Contains

INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    1, 1, 70
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    1, 3, 27
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    1, 4, 3
);


INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    2, 2, 74
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    2, 3, 21
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    2, 4, 5
);

INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    3, 1, 60
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    3, 3, 10
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    3, 5, 30
);


INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    4, 2, 95
);
INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( 
    4, 4, 5
);
```

Comment: This question contains what you're asking, what you've tried, example data and DML, and the desired results.  I wish I could upvote your question ten times, it's excellent, welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the "*contains*" table with the "*ingredient*" table using a `LEFT JOIN` and filter all values that have NULL in the "*contains.ice_cream_id*" field:

```
SELECT i.ingredient_id,
       i.ingredient_name
FROM      ingredient i
LEFT JOIN contains   c
       ON i.ingredient_id = c.ingredient_id
WHERE c.ice_cream_id IS NULL
```

Comment: You don't need the sub-query, just add `WHERE contains.ice_cream_id IS NULL` to the inner-query.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e7193a3ccdd6380e213c37d72f177fd2

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer. That was useful!

Comment: selecting `c.ice_cream_id` AND having `WHERE c.ice_cream_id IS NULL` is not very useful.

Comment: Nice catch @Luuk. Currently I'm cleaning up my past answers, didn't notice that detail.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are asking to find where somethig does *not exist*, so it would make sense to express that using `not exists`

So you just need to find the ingredients that don't exist in the list of contents:

```
select ingredient_id, ingredient_name
from ingredient i
where not exists (
  select * from contains c 
  where c.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
);
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ee02aea15f85f494793cfe46d9b51f0e)